# Tweak the TextMate's soft wrap

Tags: textmate

I don't know if this can be done globally or only in concrete bundles. If so, I'm interested in doing it only in the LaTeX files (LaTeX bundle then). If the solution only works globally, well, no problem.

At this moment, with the `Soft Wrap` option enabled (and with 80 characters per line and a `Tab size` equal to 3) this is what I get:

[image]

But I'm interested in getting all the wrapped parts of the line (those identified by a `·` instead of a line number) indented the same as the first part of the line. Like this:

[image]

But I don't want the line divided (as in the image), just that the wrapping starts from the same indented place. I.e., while I want TextMate to show me that way, there shouldn't be any *tab* in the .txt file (I mean, if I open it with another text editor it shouldn't be that way).

Is this possible? How?

Here is a more extensive example.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.textmate.general/35120) I solved it.

**Note**: This applies only to TextMate 2.

1. On the menu bar, select Bundles › Edit Bundles.
2. Within the Bundle Editor display, select LaTeX › Settings. Once here, a list of preferences indicated by
   a white P on a gray circle is seen.
3. On the menu bar again, click on New or press command-N. From the Bundle Editor display, TM will prompt you
   to choose what to create: bundle, command, setting, grammar, etc.
4. Click setting. An untitled setting will appear in the Bundle Editor window.
5. Name the new setting. I used *Soft-wrap indent*.
6. Select the new setting if not already selected.
7. In the text field, paste

   ```
   {   indentedSoftWrap = {
           match = '\A[ \t]*';
           format = '$0';
       };
   }
   ```

This enables soft-wrap indent + 1 extra tab.

8. If you wish to restrict this to a certain scope, it can be done in the drawer next to "scope selector."
   Leaving it blank will enable soft-wrap indentation for any text file.
9. Save the setting by pressing command-S and close the Bundle Editor.
10. Make sure soft wrap is enabled. (View › Soft Wrap). It might be necessary to reload any open files for the
    setting to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I've tried it myself but unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm assuming you add a new "preference" rather than "setting", and there is no option to add "setting". Has this worked for anyone else?

Comment: @Carl I suppose. And if you delete the `\t` you get the exact thing instead of (sofrwrap indent + 1).